# How to change the Indicator in ArcGIS Dashboard if value is zero?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, dashboard

I have an indicator that represents population by country as a part of my ArcGIS dashboard. The data is being pulled from a feature class which has some fields equal to 0 and I would like to insert the word "Pending"  to show if the value is 0. I cant seem to do that using the usual options and feel this is something for advanced formatting of indicators in ArcGIS dashboard?[image]

Code below:

```
return {
    //textColor:'',
    //backgroundColor:'',
    topText: 'Health Facilities',
    topTextColor: '',
    topTextOutlineColor: '',
    topTextMaxSize: 'medium',
    middleText: $datapoint["HF_Number"],
    middleTextColor: '',
    middleTextOutlineColor: '',
    middleTextMaxSize: 'large',
    //bottomText: '',
    //bottomTextColor: '',
    //bottomTextOutlineColor: '',
    //bottomTextMaxSize: 'medium',
    iconName:'icon1',
    iconAlign:'right',
    iconColor:'',
    iconOutlineColor:''
    //noValue:false,
    //attributes: {
      // attribute1: '',
      // attribute2: ''
    // }
  }
```

Comment: Whenever you request support with any issue involving ESRI systems, it is interesting to inform the version you are using, whether it is Enterprise or AGOL, as there are differences in functionality between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending of your version of ArcGIS Enterprise, There is the possibility of using Arcade functions with the indicators, and this can be done with the "IIF" function and with the "WHEN" function.

Works on Enterprise versions above 10.9.1 and with AGOL

[Documentation of Arcade Logical Functions](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/logical_functions/)

[Getting Started](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/ops-dashboard/real-time/getting-started-with-arcade-in-arcgis-dashboards/)

---

**Edit based in provided code**

Try this:

```
var hf_number = IIF($datapoint["HF_Number"] == 0, 'Pending', $datapoint["HF_Number"])
return {
        topText: 'Health Facilities',
        topTextColor: '',
        topTextOutlineColor: '',
        topTextMaxSize: 'medium',
        middleText: hf_number ,
        middleTextColor: '',
        middleTextOutlineColor: '',
        middleTextMaxSize: 'large',
        iconName:'icon1',
        iconAlign:'right',
        iconColor:'',
        iconOutlineColor:''
      }
```

Comment: If I shared the code would you be able to edit the code to display the word "pending"? That would at least give an opportunity to edit from there once I see how that can be displayed.

Comment: Sure, please edit your question with the code so that another user or I can help you

Comment: You did it! I know have alot to learn to understand the process but what you wrote is already starting to make sense to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it worked, glad it helped

Comment: @Rex_01, flag the answer as correct, to help another user to find solution